# Google Drive Sheets API create file and set ownership

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am struggling a bit with the Google API documentation for creating and sharing files on Google Drive. I am using PHP with the latest PHP libraries (2.13) via composer.

I have a service account. Although my own gmail shows as the owner in the Console permissions, Google insists on creating a fake email address as the token bearer (e.g. "xxx-yyy-account@qi-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com"). The file credentials.json generated via the console shows that email  as client email - I tried replacing it with my own email, but I get access denied (despite the fact that my own email shows as an "owner" in the project permissions.

This is the code I am running:

```php
    function create($service, $client, $title)
    {   
        try{
            $spreadsheet = new Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
                'properties' => [
                    'title' => $title
                    ]
                ]);
                $spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->create($spreadsheet, [
                    'fields' => 'spreadsheetId'
                ]);
                $spreadsheetId = $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId;
                echo "Spreadsheet ID: {$spreadsheetId} with title: {$title}\n";
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }

        $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
        $newPermission->setEmailAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
        $newPermission->setType('user');
        $newPermission->setRole('owner');
        try 
        {
            $drive->permissions->create($spreadsheetId, $newPermission);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $spreadsheetId;
    }
```

The code creates the spreadsheet ok, but I am unable to see it as it seems to be associated with the `xxx-yyy-account@qi-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com` email. The part about changing owner fails, with the error:

```
An error occurred: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "drive.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DrivePermissions.Create"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried changing the type of permissions to reader or to anyone, but they also incur the same error.

I'm not sure if it's the code or the permissions I setup. Or else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

With best wishes
Cristiano

I tried to create a new google spreadsheet and to change its ownership.

Comment: Your error message says `Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`. So, in this case, can you provide your current scopes? By the way, if your `$client` is from the service account, when you want to transfer the ownership of the files except for Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on), I'm worried that this cannot be achieved because of the current specification.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike and thank you for your reply. What I don't understand is that the files have been created by the same user/service account I am trying to use to change the ownership of the files. $client is indeed from the service account, using the credentials.json file I downloaded when creating the account. What do you mean by "provide your current scopes"? Thanks again.